Problemas de conexion entre sensores max30102 con mlx90614
Alguien me puede ayudar, necesito mostrar valores de pulso cardiaco, spo2 y temperatura corporal, pero en el monitor serial me arroja la temperatura como NaN mientras que los otros 2 datos si los muestra correctamente, estoy usando dos sensores max30102 y mlx90614 conectados a un esp32 por el mismo bus i2c, que eso puede ser que cause el problema pero no sé como solucionarlo. Ya tengo el esquema del circuito conectado correctamente y aquí está el código que estoy usando:
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MLX90614.h>
#include <MAX30105.h>

Adafruit_MLX90614 mlx = Adafruit_MLX90614();

MAX30105 particleSensor;

const int BUFFER_SIZE = 250;
int bufferIndex = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  mlx.begin();

  if (!particleSensor.begin(Wire, I2C_SPEED_FAST)) {
    Serial.println("MAX30102 was not found. Please check wiring/power.");
    while (1)
      ;
  }

  particleSensor.setup(0x1F, 4, 2, 4096);     // Configure sensor with settings for SpO2 calculation
  particleSensor.setPulseAmplitudeRed(0x0A);  // Set LED pulse amplitude for red LED
  particleSensor.setPulseAmplitudeIR(0x0A);   // Set LED pulse amplitude for IR LED

  Serial.println("------------------------------------");
  Serial.println("Connected...");
}

float calculateHeartRate(float spo2) {
  float hr = 0.0;

  if (spo2 > 90 && spo2 <= 100) {
    hr = -30.245 * spo2 + 3030.45;
  } else if (spo2 >= 80 && spo2 <= 90) {
    hr = -2.5 * spo2 + 252.5;
  } else {
    hr = -1.667 * spo2 + 166.67;
  }
  return hr;
}


void loop() {
  uint32_t ir_led, red_led;
  float ratio, spo2;

  particleSensor.check();  // Check for new data available

  ir_led = particleSensor.getIR();    // Get IR LED intensity
  red_led = particleSensor.getRed();  // Get red LED intensity

  ratio = red_led / (float)ir_led;  // Calculate ratio of red to IR LED intensity
  spo2 = 110 - 25 * ratio;          // Calculate SpO2 using Beer-Lambert Law

  float output_temp = mlx.readObjectTempC();

  float hr = calculateHeartRate(spo2);

  Serial.print("Temperature: ");
  Serial.println(output_temp);

  Serial.print("SpO2: ");
  Serial.println(spo2);

  Serial.print("HeartRate: ");
  Serial.println(hr);
  delayMicroseconds(100);  // Pauses execution for 100 microseconds
}


particleSensor.begin(Wire, I2C_SPEED_FAST) ... se supone que el primer argumento es la dirección I2C del sensor (0x5A por default) y el segundo debería ser Wire. La doc dice bool begin(uint8_t addr = MLX90614_I2CADDR, TwoWire *wire = &Wire);

A ver, me podrías pasar la documentación que explique eso por favor. Yo tengo entendido que así va: particleSensor.begin(Wire, I2C_SPEED_FAST)

Está en el header de la librería: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-MLX90614-Library/blob/master/Adafruit_MLX90614.h

Y esto esta bien como esta? "particleSensor.begin(Wire, I2C_SPEED_FAST)", eso es para iniciar el max30102
